# page up down scrolling in vbox container flex4

Tags: flex4

I want to do scrolling when page up and down key pressed in vbox container. But it is not scrolling. how to achieve this. Is there any parameters are available.

Comment: What are you currently trying? Post some code so we can spot a bug or make suggestions.